# How can I make helm-do-grep-ag show the path of the file?

Tags: ag, helm-grep

If I search with ag, then it prints the whole path of the filename, relative to the starting directory.

, but if I search with helm-do-grep-ag, it only prints the filename.

How can I make helm-do-grep-ag also print the path?;)

Also, why is it name helm-do-grep-ag, instead of helm-do-ag? Is "grep" indicating some other tool is involved?